# i want my bootstrap Carousel to 100% fit on view height of my page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I want to make my bootstrap Carousel slider to fit on view height, so whatever screen size it should automatically adjust complete height of screen so first my slider show on complete screen of any device (17 inch, 15 inch), specially when the user scrolls down to view rest of my page.
Please help me with detail!

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="images/slider_1.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Zeina Soufan</h1>
          <p>Anchor / Writer / Moderator</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read My Profile</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="images/slider_1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Zeina Soufan</h1>
          <p>Anchor / Writer / Moderator</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read My Profile</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="images/slider_1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Zeina Soufan</h1>
          <p>Anchor / Writer / Moderator</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read My Profile</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Sorry I didn't add jQuery

```
    $(document).ready( function()
{
    var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 2500;

    /*$('#carousel').carousel({
        interval:   slideInterval
    });
    */
    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#thumbCarousel').on('click', '.nav-carousel a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav-carousel li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');    
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e)
    {
        if(!clickEvent)
        {
            var count = $('.nav-carousel').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav-carousel li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id)
            {
                $('.nav-carousel li').first().addClass('active');   
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

I want some jQuery because it's responsive. When I resize the window it should adjust on resize too.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .carousel{height:100vh; width:100%;}
    .carousel-inner{height:100vh; width:100%}
    .item{height:100%; width:100%}
```